# What happen if a topology is an algebra?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space with a topology $\tau$. Suppose that $\tau$ is an algebra this immediately implies that $\tau$  is a $\sigma$-algebra. What this impose over the topological structure in $X$?

It is easy to see that this conditions implies that $\tau$ is exactly the collection of closed set. Then if for example $X$ is $T_1$ then this implies that the space has the discrete topology. The in discrete topology has this property as well and indeed is the unique topological space which its topology is a $\sigma$-algebra that is connected.

There is some characterization of this? Or there is some variety of nice examples with this property?

Comment: Here is an example: $\{\emptyset,\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{1,2,3,4\}\}$ (not Hausdorff)

Comment: You are right. If $\tau$ is Hausdorff, then each singleton set $\{x\}$ is in $\tau$.

Comment: Not much variety. If the topology is an algebra of sets, then the space is the topological sum of indiscrete subspaces (and vice versa). So if it is $T_0$, then it is discrete.

Comment: The indiscrete topology is not a topological sum of indiscrete subspaces but it still has an algebra as a topology.

Comment: @YotasTrejos A topological sum of one summand.

Comment: Of discrete subspaces I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every open set is closed and conversely.

Consider the relation $x\sim y$ on $X$ defined by $y\in\overline{\{x\}}$. The relation is clearly reflexive.

Suppose $y\in\overline{\{x\}}$. If $x\notin\overline{\{y\}}$, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $y\notin U$. Thus $U$ is a closed set containing $x$, hence $\overline{\{x\}}\subseteq U$, which implies $y\in U$: contradiction. Therefore $\sim$ is symmetric.

Suppose $x\sim y$ and $y\sim z$. If $z\notin\overline{\{x\}}$, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $z$ such that $x\notin U$. On the other hand, from $z\in\overline\{y\}$, it follows $y\in U$ and therefore $\overline{\{y\}}\subseteq U$. But $x\sim y$ implies $x\in\overline{\{y\}}$, a contradiction.

Thus $\sim$ is an equivalence relation and the equivalence classes are the closures of the singletons, which are also open.

Let $U$ be an open set. If $x\in U$, then $\overline{\{x\}}\subseteq U$, because $U$ is closed. Therefore
$$
U=\bigcup_{x\in U}\overline{\{x\}}
$$
and thus the sets $\overline{\{x\}}$ form a basis for the topology.

Conversely, if you fix an arbitrary partition of $X$ and declare it as a basis for a topology, then this topology is an algebra of sets.

Comment: Nice. Where do you find this?

Comment: @YotasTrejos I just thought to the problem and imagined how it could be dealt with